# Mask or hide an affiliate URL?

Tags: javascript, html, http, url, web-deployment

I would like to share an affiliate link that points to an iOS app in Apple's Appstore. Is it possible to mask it or create a sort of proxy to it, in a way that another user can not access it directly while at the same time maintaining its function as an affiliate link?

Comment: It wouldn't be a particularly useful link if the user can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to completely hide it, but it would be possible to hide the url from non-technical users using a few tricks.

You can put an `onclick` event handler on the link instead of an href attribute so that the user cannot get the URL by right-clicking the link.

Here's a [sample code at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FnW7/1/).